# Conditional filter multiple columns python

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have 5 columns, each of them has 0's and 1's in each row. I need to filter all those with '1' at once.

I tried this but results in error:

```
df_2 = df_1[df_1.columns[0:5] == 1]
ValueError: Item wrong length 2 instead of 111249
```

Comment: You are comparing with column names. Perhaps you want `df_1[df_1.iloc[:, :5] == 1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need `any` if want filter at least one `1` per rows of filtered columns:

```
df_2 = df_1[(df_1.columns[0:5] == 1).any(axis=1)]
```

Or `all` if want filter all `1` per rows of filtered columns:

```
df_2 = df_1[(df_1.columns[0:5] == 1).all(axis=1)]
```